# How to set ngRepeat element name in transcluded html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to write a directive to provide table formatting. The idea is that the user passes the directive the list of objects (`arr="ctrl.list"`) and the name of each object (`elem="obj"`) and supplies the transcluded format for each table element...

```
<div ng-controller="Test as ctrl">
    <test-repeat arr="ctrl.list" elem="obj">
    the element: {{obj}}
    </test-repeat>    
</div>
```

This is the directive...

```
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .directive('testRepeat', function() {
    return {
        template: 
            '<div ng-repeat="elem in arr"><span ng-transclude></span></div>',
        transclude: true,
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
            arr: '=',
            elem: '='
        },
        link: function($scope, $elem, $attr) {
        }
    };    
});
```

And the controller:

```
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('Test', function() {    
        var self = this;
        self.list = [ {title: 'one'}, {title: 'two'}, {title: 'three'} ];
});
```

While the array value (`arr="ctrl.list"`) is properly bound to the directive scope and used by `ng-repeat` the `elem` value isn't, likely because these two variables are treated very differently by the `ng-repeat` directive.

Is it possible to re-write this directive to make the `ng-repeat` code use the value of `elem` specified by the user (i.e. `obj`)? And if I need to write my own version of `ng-repeat` using the `transclude` function (passed as a parameter to the `link` function) how would I watch each element of the array like `ng-repeat` does?

Here is a [link](https://jsfiddle.net/kergoog/whvctzvn/31/) to the jsfiddle.

**Edit**

As requested the desired output would be...

```
the element: {"title":"one"}
the element: {"title":"two"}
the element: {"title":"three"}
```

With the example of the html shown above (i.e. `the element: {{obj}}`). The broader idea being that the user could customise how they want `obj` to be displayed though.

Comment: Please show us what your desired output would be.

Comment: Have edited the post accordingly...

Comment: The `elem` in ng-repeat doesn't get bound to the scope, so you can't export it out of the directive like that. You can only use that variable within the ng-repeat container.

Comment: If, and it's a big if, I understand that post correctly it's quite different from my question. It looks like the name `$item` is hard-coded into the `template` variable in the link function.